# What is an acceptable time to mark a question as resolved?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Should I be marking them as I find answers that are better than prior ones? I think that would give people a lot of unnecessary notifications. Or maybe I should check back in 2 days? 3 days? a week?

Is there some sorta guideline on this?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you.